# Count the seconds for long holding touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch

I'm trying to count the seconds for holding a tap on the screen or a specific view object.

There are some touch events like touchDownInside, touchUpInside, touchesBegan, and many more, but what method can perform holding touch?

Comment: its called [UILongPressGestureRecognizer. Check it out in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following two methods and add the property. Comment the button "Touch Down" event to the `touchDown:` method and the "Touch Up Inside" event to the `touchUp:` method.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *touchDownTime;

- (IBAction)touchDown:(id)sender {
    self.touchDownTime = [NSDate date];
}

- (IBAction)touchUp:(id)sender {
    NSTimeInterval timeDown = [self.touchDownTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
    NSLog(@"'timeDown: %0.1f sec", timeDown);
}
```

If you need to do something every second (or some interval) start a timer in `touchDown` and invalidate in `touchUp`.

Answer (score 0):

As @NewEngland says, you should use a UILongPressGestureRecognizer. Those gesture recognizers are continuous, so it will send you notifications when the gesture begins and when it ends.

If you want a visual display of seconds you can start a timer when the gesture begins that fires every second to update your counter, and invalidate the timer when the gesture ends.

If you just need to count the number of seconds that the user holds the gesture numerically, save the current time using the NSDate class method timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate when the gesture begins, and then get the new time when the gesture ends and subtract the end interval from the start interval to get the number of seconds the user held the gesture.